# How do I change desktop environment in Ubuntu 17.10 if user has no password?

Tags: desktop-environments, 17.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 from Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop that I let my family use, and none of them have passwords. But when they try to log in, it defaults to Kodi. How do I change the desktop environment without giving them passwords?

Answer (score 0):

I remember changing the `XSession` to `ubuntu` or `gnome-org` in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<user-name>`, to resolve same issue. It worked after restarting. My current file looks something like this.

```
[InputSource0]
 xkb=us

[User]
 XSession=ubuntu
 SystemAccount=false
```

(When creating new user, make sure you have correct `DefaultSession` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, as the same would apply to it.)

Comment: There has to be an easier way than this. It woudl be easier for me to just give everyone passwords.